# cocoa mac osx grid display of images of different sizes

Tags: image, macos, cocoa, gridview, size

what i'm trying to do is displaying a set of images in a grid like fashion but with different sizes as for images in landscape or portrait position, this excludes using the NSCollectionView because the item prototype's size can only be set once...

i'd go and add subviews programmatically to a scrollView but this yet again when the window's size changes and the scrollView get a bigger width, there will be just blank spaces on the right side...

you can checkout the image below for a better understanding...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVJjP.png

thanks in advance you guys...

Comment: Please upload the image or images to stackoverflow directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i ended up doing was implementing a purely mathematic algorithm where i calculated the (x,y) position for every new added photo depending on the previously added photos and it did a pretty good job... the container holding the photos was embedded in a scrollView, needless to say that i had to calculate the height of this container as well.